# how do i pass a variable to another php file without include?

Tags: php, mysql

how would I pass the variable $u to another php file without using include or anything similar? 
Am I right in thinking that the u is fetched ($_GET) from the url?

```
if(isset($_GET["u"])){
   $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it via [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

**GET:**

file1.php

```
<?php
$u = 'something';
echo '<a href="http://website.com/file2.php?u=' . $u . '">Click me!</a>';
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['u'])) {
    echo $_GET['u'];
}
?>
```

**Sessions:**

file1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['u'])) {
    $_SESSION['u'] = 'something';
}
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['u'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['u'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you right. For your purposes you need to use `$_SESSION` and session mechanism or cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 'u' is fetched from the url.  e.g.  http://domain.tld/index.php?u=bob will produce 'bob' as 'u'.  Add u=whatever to the url and the 'u' will be on that page or if you don't want to do that you will need to store it in a session and/or cookie.